# How To call API using JavaScript , json or ajax

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

Search type:
Method : POST

URL:  http: // beta.etruckingsoft.com:8800/contact/searchContacts

BODY:

```
{"Company Id" : 2, 
"SearchVal" : "b",
"Contact Type":"Broker",
"token" : "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.MTkzMA.g132LGIzcwJaJRGa31q-k1hk6u79H0wIj1xjCJzLpZU"}

CONTACT-TYPE : application/json
```

How to call this API using JavaScript, ajax or json method?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Mohammed. Please take some time to read the help page, especially [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You might also want to read the [Stack Overflow question checklist by Jon Skeet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(), url="http://beta.etruckingsoft.com:8800/contact/searchContacts", method="POST";
const body = {
    "Company Id" : 2,
    "SearchVal" : "b",
    "Contact Type":"Broker",
    "token" : "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.MTkzMA.g132LGIzcwJaJRGa31q-k1hk6u79H0wIj1xjCJzLpZU"
};
xhr.open(method, url, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200)
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
    };
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(body));
```